Syncthing transfer to Ubuntu 24.04 extremely slow. Anyone else?
Ever since I upgraded my Laptop to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, it syncs my Android phone's folder (6 files, about 8GB) laughably slow at 150Kib/s.
On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it was 30Mbit/s.
Anyone else with the same problem?

Is it still slow now?

24.04 seems very slow in general, compared to jammy, I just updated now (October 2024) hoping that the bugs had been solved, but apparently they haven't
